# Writing rviz plugin in python

Tags: ros, python, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and rviz.

I want to write a new tool rviz plugin like the one in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Plugins%3A%20New%20Tool%20Type) (adding a new tool on the tool bar), but in python rather than C++. My plugin tool needs to be able to create a line by dragging the mouse across the display in rviz. (I'm just practicing to write a simple tool here.)

I couldn't find any helpful resources or documentations on writing rviz plugin in python, nor a plugin written in python that I can reference on. Does anyone know any tutorial or resources or a sample plugin that might help?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238172/writing-rviz-plugin-in-python/) by [ms0719584](https://answers.ros.org/users/27301/ms0719584/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-27**:
Afaik, it's not possible to write RViz plugins in Python (or at least, not without instantiating a Python interpreter in your C++ plugin class and then using that to run Python (but even that would need bindings of some sort)). Let's hope someone responds to your question that proves me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There  is an old [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_python_tutorial?distro=kinetic) on how to do it the other way around. Using import librviz Python bindings to get Rviz`s 3D visualizer and adding your functionality. The tutorial displays a grid of variable line width.

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0